# removing the null value in a toString method

Tags: nullpointerexception, null, tostring

so im trying to solv this question, I am not allowed to see the rest of the code because it is an old exam question. basically I have to make a toString method to printout firstName,middleName, lastName. here is the problem my toString method works correctly until the testprogram throws a null value in one of the (firstName, middleName or lastName) slots. my code should be able to recognise this null value and skip it.
how can I fix this.
this is my code below.

public class Person {

```
// Ändra inget på nedanstående rad
String firstName, middleName, lastName;

public String toString(){

    return firstName + " " + middleName +" "+ lastName ;
    
}
```

}

output:
Expected: John Fitzgerald Kennedy

Got: John Fitzgerald Kennedy

Expected: Alan Turing
Got: Alan null Turing

Comment: You presumably know enough Java to test if a variable is null, so what is preventing you implementing this code? Also, if this is Java then you should tag the question accordingly.

Answer (score -3):

below is a code as per my knowledge about your issue, If it is related to exception use try-catch block of code with java

```
public class H{

 public static void main(String []args){
    
    Person p1=new Person("VKR",null,"R");
   
    System.out.println(p1.toString());
 }
```

}

```
class Person
{

String firstName, middleName, lastName;
Person(String name,String Mid,String Last)
{
    firstName=name;
    middleName=Mid;
    lastName=Last;

}

public String toString(){
    if( firstName!=null && middleName!=null &&  lastName!=null)
    {
        return firstName + " " + middleName +" "+ lastName ;
    }
    else 
    return " ";
}
```

}

Comment: Not an ideal return value if middleName alone is null (a common occurrence). And not a good default value (single space)  in any case.